# Bathroom Ceiling Fan

Tags: electrical

Trying to install a Utiltech bath ceiling fan light (the old fan died). I can't seem to get the wiring right. Fan/light has two whites, two blacks and a neutral. House wiring is red, white black and neutral. I just can't figure out the wiring. Can you help. Two switches on the wall.  Trying to wire so one switch works the fan and the other the light.

Comment: Important: What you are calling neutral is actually **ground**. In US wiring, white is *usually* neutral (but not always, there are a bunch of allowable exceptions), black, red, blue, yellow, etc. are "hot" of some variety (hot, switched hot, traveler - but no way to tell via color) and bare and green are **always and only ground**. Neutral and ground are connected in exactly one place (the main panel) if everything is done according to code, and confusion between neutral and ground can cause a **lot** of problems, including dangerous situations.

Comment: You might get yourself a good basic house wiring resource and do some reading. This is about as simple a circuit as they come, and your lack of familiarity with that and what manessehkatz said leave me concerned about other things you may not know, such as how to work safely and make safe connections.

Comment: I'm calling the ground "neutral".  Sorry for that.  I assume green to green is correct?